Points having large section of large set is large
This is a question I encountered in reading the proof of Lemma 2.2 in Strict Ergodicity and Transformation of the Torus, H. Furstenberg. One claim he makes is not clear to me and I separately pose that as question below, hoping it has all necessary assumptions.
Let ($\Omega_1,\mu_1$) be a probability space where $\mu_1$ is a borel probability measure and assume $\Omega_1$ is a metric space. Let $(\mathbb{S^1},m)$ be the unit circle with normalised lebesgue measure $m$. Then $\Omega_0= \Omega_1 \times \mathbb{S^1}$ equipped with product measure $\mu_0=\mu_1 \times m$ is a probability space. Let $\Lambda  \subset \Omega_0$ be a measurable set with $\mu_0(\Lambda) > 1-\delta$ for some pre given $\delta \in (0,1/2)$. And define $\Lambda_1 \subset \Omega _1$ as,
$\Lambda_1=\{\omega_1 \in \Omega_1: m ( \xi: (\omega_1,\xi) \in \Lambda) >1-\sqrt\delta\}$
Then show that, $\mu_1(\Lambda_1) >1-\sqrt\delta$.
(I want assistance in showing that $\mu_1(\Lambda_1) >1-\sqrt\delta$)

It's still unclear to me: You want assistance in showing that $\mu_1(\Lambda_1) > 1-\sqrt\delta$?

Define the measurable function $f : \Omega_1 \rightarrow [0, 1]$ as
$$f(\omega_1) = m\left( \{ \xi \in \mathbb{S}^1  : (\omega_1, \xi) \in \Lambda  \}\right)$$
By Fubini's theorem, we can write $\mu_0(\Lambda)$ as
$$\mu_0(\Lambda) = \int_{\Omega_0} \mathbf{1}_{\Lambda}(\omega_1, \xi) d\mu_0(\omega_1, \xi) = \int_{\Omega_1} \left( \int_{\mathbb{S}_1} \mathbf{1}_{\Lambda}(\omega_1, \xi) dm(\xi) \right)d\mu_1(\omega_1) = \int_{\Omega_1} f(\omega_1) d\mu_1(\omega_1)$$
As $\mu_0(\Lambda) > 1 - \delta$ we have
$$1 - \mu_0(\Lambda) = \int_{\Omega_1} \left(1 - f(\omega_1) \right) d\mu_1(\omega_1) < \delta$$
Consider the set $A = \{ \omega_1 \in \Omega_1 : 1 - f(\omega_1) > \sqrt{\delta}\}$. We can bound the integral over $A$ as
$$\int_{A} \left( 1 - f(\omega_1) \right) d\mu_1(\omega_1) > \sqrt{\delta} \mu_1(A)$$
At the same time, as $A \subseteq \Omega_1$ we know that
$$\int_{A} \left( 1 - f(\omega_1) \right) d\mu_1(\omega_1) \le \int_{\Omega_1}\left( 1 - f(\omega_1) \right) d\mu_1(\omega_1) < \delta$$
This means that $\sqrt{\delta}\mu_1(A) < \delta$, and so $\mu_1(A) < \sqrt{\delta}$. But by the definition of $A$ it holds that
$$\mu_1(\Lambda_1) = \mu_1(\Omega_1 \setminus A) > 1 - \sqrt{\delta}$$
as required.

You mean $\mu_0(\Lambda) = \int_{\Omega_0} \mathbf{1}{\Lambda}(\omega_1, \xi) d\mu_0(\omega_1, \xi)$  instead of $\mu_0(\Lambda) = \int{\Omega_1} \mathbf{1}_{\Lambda}(\omega_1, \xi) d\mu_0(\omega_1, \xi)$?

yes, good catch. Edited.
